# VIM - Bat to convert character encodings

Tags: batch-file, csv, vim, encoding, character-encoding

I have a .csv file downloaded from Google Drive in a codification that doesnt recognize accented characters (spanish characters).

With the VIM editor for Windows I'm able to solve this problem by opening the file (vim spanish.csv) and then inside the file type

```
 :write ++enc=utf-16 spanish-2.csv
```

Now I need to create a .bat or .ps1 to automatically do this for me. How can I do this?

P.D.: I've tried using iconv and I can't convert the file that I download from Google Drive since I don't know in with codification it is. I tried:

```
iconv -f ANSI:X3.4-1968 -t UTF-8 spanish.csv > spanish-2.csv
iconv -f ANSI:X3.4-1986 -t UTF-8 spanish.csv > spanish-2.csv
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8 spanish.csv > spanish-2.csv
```

And many other encodings but it says that the file can't be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### find out the encoding

When you've opened the `spanish.csv` source file within Vim,

```
:setlocal fileencoding?
```

should tell you the detected encoding. There are also third-party tools like `enca` that can do this detection. You then only potentially need to translate the encoding name into the format expected by `iconv`.

#### convert with Vim

You can also directly use Vim for the conversion; Ex commands can be specified on the command-line via `-c {cmd}`:

```
vim -c "write ++enc=utf-16 spanish-2.csv" -c "quit" spanish.csv
```

With the use of `:argdo`, and a file name of `%:r-2.%:e`, you can even pass multiple source files to a single Vim instance for conversion.

Comment: Sir you made my day. Thanks you so much.. "vim -c "write ++enc=utf-16 spanish-2.csv" -c "quit" spanish.csv" did the work